# Is it possible to build an email reader for the Zune?

Tags: .net, xna, zune, xna-3.0

Is it possible to build an email reader for the Zune through XNA ?

Version 3.0 allows us to connect to the Market place and download music directly from the Zune hence the nature of my question.

Edit: Buy a ZuneHD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

XNA 3.0 for the Zune does offer some networking classes, but it appears that they are specifically for talking to other devices (for multi-player games).

So while you MIGHT be able to make a peer-to-peer chat program or something, you wouldn't be able to consume server-side resources like email.

[Here's a thread](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/11797.aspx) with links to some networking samples:

Edit: I found the [official FAQ](http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/8911/46553.aspx):

---

Q: How does the wireless support work?

A: The Zune device can support multiple Zunes that have wireless turned on and are within range of each other.  If all the Zunes have the game deployed, and the game is written to work in a multiplayer mode, you can join in and play games with other Zunes.

**Q: Can we talk to a webserver or an RSS-feed through the wireless connection?**

**A: The Zune wireless connection has no internet support.  It only enables you to play games with other nearby Zunes, along with other standard Zune features (i.e., music sharing, etc.)**